# Quadratic Word Problems

Tags: linear-algebra

A dealer sells CDs for 6 dollars  and usually sells 20. If he lowers the price by 2 dollars, he will increase sales by 8 Cds. How many does he have to sell to earn $96.

This is what I have done so far: 
The equation for this problem is 96=(6-2x)(20+8x)

I thin I should use the quadratic formula to solve for x. But, then x means the number of times the dealer should lowering the price. So, do I still need to find the axis of symmetry?

Comment: Using the quadratic formula, I have x=-1, 1.5. I know he has to sell 32 CDs to earn 96 dollars. But, why can't we use x=-1?

Comment: $x$ is -1 or 1.5

Answer (score 0):

Both your solutions are correct. A negative price decrease is a price increase.

If he increases the price by 2 dollars $(x=-1)$, then he sells $(20-8)$ at $(6+2)$ or $12$ at $8$ dollars or $96$ dollars.

If he decreases the price by $(2 \times 1.5)$ $(x=1.5)$ then he sells $(20+8 \times 1.5)$  at $(6-2 \times 1.5)$ or $32$ at $3$ dollars or 96 dollars...

Comment: Thank you. This helped me understand it better.